# Attempt to do TLS over UDP: wsarecv error about large message

Tags: go, ssl, udp

I want get tls conn base on udp, just like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    var buf []byte = make([]byte, 2000)
    for {
        if n, err := conn.Read(buf); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            conn.Write(buf[:n])
        }
    }
}

func server() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./serve.cert.pem", "./serve.key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    config := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19986}, &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19987})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tconn := tls.Server(conn, config)
    defer tconn.Close()

    if err = tconn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    handleConn(tconn)
}

func main() {

    go server()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    client()
}

func client() {
    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19987}, &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19986})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tconn := tls.Client(conn, conf)
    defer tconn.Close()

    if err = tconn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    n, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
}
```

panic:

```sh
panic: read udp 127.0.0.1:19987->127.0.0.1:19986: wsarecv: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.client()
        D:/OneDrive/code/go/ctest/main.go:65 +0x2d1
main.main()
        D:/OneDrive/code/go/ctest/main.go:49 +0x34
exit status 2
```

Appendix：
serve.cert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBbjCCARSgAwIBAgIRAI+jBYEYS5aBXDUedBt7PKYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwEjEQ
MA4GA1UEChMHQWNtZSBDbzAeFw0yMjAxMDkxNzQxMjBaFw0yMzAxMDkxNzQxMjBa
MBIxEDAOBgNVBAoTB0FjbWUgQ28wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAQy
l1/gWhTxZ3rS/XJOMLHhmkQp64EtPrEgq9SjKDpWBZQC+kNZdM5xzJrv3bLqcyOS
JywZfEpTZzW7sxko4maBo0swSTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYI
KwYBBQUHAwEwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAUBgNVHREEDTALgglsb2NhbGhvc3QwCgYI
KoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAICxMC8o603GwL3bf42EXrtPP5/LtEIc/hjdJpilqc3b
AiBTEdrE+/oCgUjsxV2RFj1+42CTGtcav4sJyCPjme0N/w==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

serve.key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgmH+BleetLN1fK0dy
JpedWG8C2yxtb7gEEAwvdwXf6FihRANCAAQyl1/gWhTxZ3rS/XJOMLHhmkQp64Et
PrEgq9SjKDpWBZQC+kNZdM5xzJrv3bLqcyOSJywZfEpTZzW7sxko4maB
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I try set udp conn's buff, useless!
The certificate only 558 Bytes, but the UDP has a capacity of 65536 Bytes. then, I debug found: in `crypt/tls/conn.go>readRecordOrCCS c.readFromUntil(c.conn, recordHeaderLen)`, the `recordHeaderLen` is constant 5, it add bytes.MinRead; so the reader buff's len is 517. Actually data size about 700 Bytes.
So? What should I do?

Comment: The panic cause by client's handshake

Comment: UDP is not a streaming protocol, every write must fit into a single datagram, and every read must consume the entire predetermined datagram size (and there of course is no guarantee of delivery to begin with)

Comment: TLS is not designed for use with an unreliable protocol like UDP. TLS requires that no data get lost, reordered or duplicated and UDP does not match these requirements. For use with unreliable transports like UDP there is DTLS instead.

Comment: See also quic/http3

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sensibly expect to make the thing work: TLS (and SSL) is designed to be carried out using the application layer of another protocol.
What this means in simpler terms is that while TLS is oblivious to what particular protocol transports its bytes, as a client of the application layer, it expects two properties from the underlying stack: it transports arbitrary opaque streams of data, ensuring robustness and in-order delivery.
In the TCP/IP world, this means TCP because UDP does not provide neither of the properties TLS expects.

Still, some solutions do successfully employ TLS over UDP, with [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net) being a prime example of this—it uses TLS for handshake and initial key exchange while having UDP as its default, and recommended, transport protocol,—but all of them have a layer implemented over UDP which "arms" it with the properties typically found in TCP: such layers deal with dropped, reordered, duplicated and corrupted UDP frames, "exporting" to the upper layer a protocol which is OK to use for application layer.

This basically means than if you're after using TLS over UDP, you first need to implemet a custom type having the `net.Conn` interface which would use a UDP association to shovel the bytes back and forth and "export" to its client a connection which has the properties of robustness and in-order delivery—just as `net.TCPConn` does.

Comment: FYI, the new HTTP3 standard uses TLS over UDP.

Comment: @ShellCode, strictly speaking, that is not correct—to cite RFC 9001: «QUIC [RFC 9000] assumes responsibility for the confidentiality and integrity protection of packets. For this it uses keys derived from a TLS handshake [RFC 8446], but instead of carrying TLS records over QUIC (as with TCP), TLS handshake and alert messages are carried directly over the QUIC transport, which takes over the responsibilities of the TLS record layer». But the point is, HTTP3 does not use TLS over UDP, it rather uses bits of TLS over QUIC which is not UDP; it uses UDP but implements some properties of TCP.

Comment: I agree that my message is overly simplified and not quite accurate. You're right that there's an added layer (QUIC) on top of UDP which takes care of various things TCP usually takes care of for you, but even though TLS is not performed over "raw UDP", in the end it still uses datagrams. So I don't believe `the new HTTP3 standard uses TLS over UDP` is wrong per se

Comment: @ShellCode, well, OK. I think my reaction was mostly because it's instilled in my brain since forever that TLS presupposes using of a stream-like transport (so its precursor has even had the word "socket" in its name), and for most practical applications it's TCP ;-) It's like you can surely shovel HTTP over, say, a `pipe(2)` or `socketpair(2)`, but most of the time when someone speaks about HTTP, the implied context is that TCP/IP is used as a transport.

Comment: True, when I learned about the existence of HTTP3 I was pretty mind blown to see it work over UDP, it goes against everything I thought I knew. But over the years it's being used more and more, specially by big tech companies which face huge performance challenges. One day it might become the norm for anyone running a webserver so we better be ready :)

Answer (score -1):

I GOT IT!

just make udp conn become to stream io.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    var buf []byte = make([]byte, 2000)
    for {
        if n, err := conn.Read(buf); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
            conn.Write(append([]byte("got: "), buf[:n]...))
        }
    }
}

func server() {
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./serve.cert.pem", "./serve.key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    config := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19986}, &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19987})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sconn := NewSconn(conn)
    tconn := tls.Server(sconn, config)
    defer tconn.Close()

    handleConn(tconn)
}

func main() {

    go server()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    client()
}

func client() {
    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        CipherSuites: []uint16{
            tls.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        },
    }

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19987}, &net.UDPAddr{Port: 19986})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sconn := NewSconn(conn)
    tconn := tls.Client(sconn, conf)
    defer tconn.Close()

    _, err = tconn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    n, err := tconn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(buf[:n]))
}

//
//
//
//
// --------------------------------------------------
type sconn struct {
    conn net.Conn

    buf  *bytes.Buffer
    rLen int
    lock sync.Mutex
}

func NewSconn(conn net.Conn) *sconn {
    return &sconn{
        conn: conn,

        buf:  bytes.NewBuffer(nil),
        rLen: 2000,
        lock: sync.Mutex{},
    }
}

func (s *sconn) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    if s.buf.Len() != 0 {
        n, err = s.buf.Read(b)
    } else {
        s.push(&s.rLen)
        n, err = s.buf.Read(b)

    }
    return n, err
}

// push push UDP package to buff
func (s *sconn) push(rLen *int) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            if *rLen < 65536 {
                *rLen = *rLen + 2000
                s.push(rLen)
            } else {
                err = errors.New(fmt.Sprintln(e))
            }
        }
    }()
    var tmp []byte = make([]byte, *rLen)
    if n, err := s.conn.Read(tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        _, err := s.buf.Write(tmp[:n])
        return err
    }
}

func (s *sconn) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {

    for i := 0; i < len(b); i = i + 512 {
        j := i + 512
        if j > len(b) {
            j = len(b)
        }
        if n, err = s.conn.Write(b[i:j]); err != nil {
            return n, err
        }
    }
    return len(b), nil
}

func (s *sconn) Close() error                       { return nil } // only close TLS conn, don't close UDP conn
func (s *sconn) LocalAddr() net.Addr                { return s.conn.LocalAddr() }
func (s *sconn) RemoteAddr() net.Addr               { return s.conn.RemoteAddr() }
func (s *sconn) SetDeadline(t time.Time) error      { return s.conn.SetDeadline(t) }
func (s *sconn) SetReadDeadline(t time.Time) error  { return s.conn.SetReadDeadline(t) }
func (s *sconn) SetWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error { return s.conn.SetWriteDeadline(t) }
```

Comment: you did not solve the problem here; You solved something yes, but the nature of the problem is much different. @kostix did explain that and your solution does not address any of those concerns. IRL this code will break randomly.

Comment: @mh-cbon, If the "break randomly"  cause by UDP's unreliable, It's ok for me.

Comment: No, it will break because you can't use bufio directly on a UDP connection, _because UDP is not a stream!_. Writes must always fit within the datagram size, and corresponding reads must always match that datagram size. In this implementation there will be partial reads which discard data. You can of course implement a streaming protocol on top of UDP, it's been done many many times, but this is not the way to do it.